# SQL Server does not choose to use index although everything seems to suggest it

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Something is wrong here and I don't understand what. It's worth to mention, there searched value is not in the table, for an existing value there is no problem. Though, why does the first query require a clustered key search for the primary key which is not even used in the query, while the second can run on the index directly.
Forcing the query to use the index WITH(INDEX(indexname)) does work, but why does the optimizer not choose to use it by itself.

The column PIECE_NUM is not in any other index and is also not the primary key.

```sql
SET STATISTICS IO ON

    DECLARE  @vchEventNum   VARCHAR(50)
    SET  @vchEventNum = '54235DDS28KC1F5SJQMWZ'

    SELECT TOP 1 
            fwt.WEIGHT,
            fwt.TEST_RESULT
    FROM FIN_WEIGHT_TESTS fwt WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE fwt.PIECE_NUM LIKE @vchEventNum  + '%'  
    ORDER BY fwt.DTTM_INSERT DESC


    SELECT TOP 1 
            fwt.WEIGHT,
            fwt.TEST_RESULT
    FROM FIN_WEIGHT_TESTS fwt WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE fwt.PIECE_NUM LIKE '54235DDS28KC1F5SJQMWZ'  + '%'  
    ORDER BY fwt.DTTM_INSERT DESC

SET STATISTICS IO OFF
```

I let both queries run in one batch:

IO statistics report:

Query 1: **logical reads 16244910**

Query 2: **logical reads 5**

```
Table 'FIN_WEIGHT_TESTS'. Scan count 1, logical reads 16244910, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table 'FIN_WEIGHT_TESTS'. Scan count 1, logical reads 5, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

The table has a non-clustered index on PIECE_NUM INCLUDING all three other columns from the query.

Here are the query execution plans(with a little editing to remove the actual names):
[image]

I noticed the convert_implicit, but that is just due to conversion of the varchar parameter to nvarchar column. Changing the parameter type did not change the behaviour of the query.

Why does the query with the parameter not use the index while replacing the parameter with its value does?

Comment: 1 - Please **don't** randomly use nolock: https://sqlstudies.com/2015/03/18/why-not-nolock/

Comment: 2 - Read up on Parameter Sniffing: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/

Comment: @Milney Thanks for the link, will read more about nolock as it is heavily used all across our database. Here it is not my code, I just wanted to figure out why this query creates billions of reads each day.

Also will read about parameter sniffing. Here I thought all hints were there for the optimizer to know what to do - only one conditional column, only one index where this column is in.

Answer (score 2):

The first query is  going to scan because you are using a local variable.  The optimizer sees this as an "anonymous" value and therefore cannot use statistics to build a good query plan.

The second query seeks because it is a literal value and SQL can look into it's stats and knows much better how many estimated rows it will find with that value.

If you run your first query as follows I would imagine you will see it use the better plan:

```
DECLARE  @vchEventNum   VARCHAR(50)
SET  @vchEventNum = '54235DDS28KC1F5SJQMWZ'

SELECT TOP 1 
        fwt.WEIGHT,
        fwt.TEST_RESULT
FROM FIN_WEIGHT_TESTS fwt WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE fwt.PIECE_NUM LIKE @vchEventNum  + '%'
ORDER BY fwt.DTTM_INSERT DESC
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

I would suggest using a parameterized procedure to run this code to ensure that it uses a cached plan.  Using the RECOMPILE hint has it's own drawbacks as the optimizer will need to rebuild the plan every time it runs.  So if you run this code very often I would avoid this hint.

You can read about local variables here:https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/06/tuning-stored-procedures-local-variables-problems/

Comment: That is all right about variable but still no explanation of WHY did it choose clustered + non clustered when non clustered has ALL the requested fields

Comment: "suggest using a parameterized procedure" - not sure what you mean. The code is within a stored procedure, however the @vchEventNum is a local variable within the SP.

Comment: When you use a local variable it cannot be sniffed unless you use recompile option. If instead you use @vchEventNum as a sp's parameter, it's sniffed at the first proc compilation and the plan will be built for that sniffed value, the estimation will be more accurate and the second plan will be chosen

Comment: I guess forcing the query to use the correct index might be the better solution compared to recompile.

Comment: @sepupic Ok, thanks, now it's clear, but it's not an option to give the value in the variable as a parameter to the SP. So I'll stick to the WITH(index()).

Comment: No, if you cannot pass that variable as a parameter, the best way is to use option (OPTIMIZE FOR (@vchEventNum = '54235DDS28KC1F5SJQMWZ' )).This will cause the optimizer to think you pass that constant, and it will use statistics and will figure out that there are only few rows with this value and the second plan will win. In case you use index hint your code will breake once that index is unavailable

Comment: But the value for @vchEventNum is retrieved by a query in the SP. I guess OPTIMIZE FOR (@vchEventNum =  @vchEventNum) won't work as good :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the cause of what happened is both use of `@variable` and `ORDER BY` in your query. To test my guess remove `order by` from your query and it may lead to equal plans in both cases (this time with different estimated number of rows reported in select).

As mentioned in previous answer, local variables cannot be sniffed at compilation time as the batch is seen as a whole thing, and only `recompile` option permits to server to know the value of a variable at the compilation time as recompilation begins when the variable is already assigned. This leads to "estimate for unknown" in the first case i.e. statistics cannot be used as we don't know the value in the filter, more rows in output are estimated.

But the query has `top + order by` in it. This means that if we expect many rows, to get only one but the first ordered by `DTTM_INSERT DESC` we must `sort`  all the filtered rows. In fact if you look at the second plan you see that the `SORT` operator costs most of all. But when you use the constant, SQL Server uses the statistics and finds out that there will be only one row returned, so it can permit to sort the result.

In case of many rows expected it decides to use the index that is already ordered by `DTTM_INSERT`. It's only my guess because you did not post here the creation scripts for your indexes but from the plan I see that the first plan surely goes to the clustered index to grab the fields that are missing in non-clustered index, this means it's not the same non clustered that is used in the second case, but I'm sure the index chosen in the first case has `THE LEADING KEY COLUMN DTTM_INSERT`. Doing so server eliminates the `sort` that we see in the second plan

Comment: Thanks, will have to read your post a third time to get it all, but you were right, removing the ORDER BY eliminates the scan and the query plan is the same (just with a scalar calculation and constant scan for the variable), yet the order by is necessary as there might be older values.
Yes there is another index just for DTTM_INSERT. Still I don't get it why the first query searches the primary key.

Comment: The first plan uses the index that has DTTM_INSERT **ORDERED** to avoid SORT operation. But it still needs the missing fields that it lookups in the clustered index. ORDERED is the key here. You asked the server to return you some values that correspond to MAX(DTTM_INSERT) and that index has DTTM_INSERT values already sorted. All it needs now is to grab missing values and apply the filter